# SQLite not working with Redux in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite, redux, expo

After introducing Redux to my React Native Expo app, whenever I try to interact with the database my app stops working.

actions.js:

```
export const SET_SELECTED_PLAYERS = "SET_SELECTED_PLAYERS"
export const SET_PLAYERS = "SET_PLAYERS"
export const SET_SELECTED_COURSE = "SET_SELECTED_COURSE"
export const SET_COURSES = "SET_COURSES"

//Player actions

export const setPlayers = (players) => (
    { type: SET_PLAYERS, payload: players, }
)

export const setSelectedPlayers = (players) => (
    ({ type: SET_SELECTED_PLAYERS, payload: players, })
)

export const setSelectedCourse = (course) =>
    ({ type: SET_SELECTED_COURSE, payload: course, })

export const setCourses = (courses) =>
    ({ type: SET_COURSES, payload: courses, })
```

reducers.js:

```
import { SET_PLAYERS, SET_SELECTED_PLAYERS, SET_SELECTED_COURSE, SET_COURSES } from "./actions"

const initialState = {
    players: [],
    selectedPlayers: [],
    courses: [],
    selectedCourse: null,
    round: {}
}

export const playerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_PLAYERS:
            return { ...state, players: action.payload }
        case SET_SELECTED_PLAYERS:
            return { ...state, selectedPlayers: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const courseReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_SELECTED_COURSE:
            return { ...state, selectedCourse: action.payload }
        case SET_COURSES:
            return { ...state, courses: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { courseReducer, playerReducer } from "./reducers";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ playerReducer, courseReducer })

export const Store = createStore(rootReducer)
```

SQLite used in component :

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const db = SQLite.openDatabase("players.db")
useEffect(() => {
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Player", [], (trans, result) => {
            dispatch(setPlayers(result.rows._array))
        })
    })
}, [])
```

Table for Player exists and app worked before I introduced Redux. It interacts with Firebase and when fetching data from cloud Redux has no problems. What problems could it have with SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite query in redux action

```js
export const getUsers = () => {
  try {
    return async dispatch => {
      const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      const json = await result.json();
      if (json) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USERS,
          payload: json
        })
      } else {
        console.log('fetch user api error');
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('action error');
  }
}
```